# InfoPath 2010 - multiple digital certificates / repeating section

Tags: infopath, digital-certificate, repeat

How can I implement a digital signiture/certificate for each line of a repeating group of data ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. When you sign a group of data it locks the entire group (so no one else can add or remove from that group. You might have to find a creative way around it (type initials in a text box for each repeating group and then sign the entire form for example). You could also try and put a section in your repeating group and have the signature just apply to the section (not the entire group). Not sure if InfoPath will be able to resolve that correctly but you could try.